# loopback add item to property array by api not inject ctx

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

In loopbackjs the follow api not working.
PUT /Bookstore/{id}/books/rel/{fk} Add a related item by id for books.

I define in phase of boot

```
app.remotes().before('*.*', inject);
app.remotes().before('*.prototype.*', function(ctx, instance, next) {
   inject(ctx, next);
});
```

function inject add to options more information.

But in this case the first operation is 
Model.observe('access',.... define in mixin and not inject.

The api fail.
Someone has already had the same problem?

Comment: Could explain the goal of your code? I am not sure what did you try to achieve with this sample code. What is inject function?

Comment: Look at this  link https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3567